# Как сделать return для родительской функции используя дочернюю

Tags: javascript

```
function loadjs(filename) {
    $.getScript("https://"+UMBRELLA.stat+"/v4/"+filename).done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){
        return true;
    });
}
```

Как нужно сделать чтобы loadjs возвращал значение true после того как файл через getScript будет загружен. В указанном выше коде я хотел чтобы return true; был для loadjs()

Заранее благодарю за советы!

Answer (score 3):

Так как вы хотите, сделать нельзя.

Но можно сделать немного по-другому:

Вам надо чтобы по окончанию загрузки выполнялось какое-то действие. Вы можете его впихнуть в функцию loadjs в качестве параметров. Будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
function loadjs(filename, callback, scope) {
    $.getScript("https://"+UMBRELLA.stat+"/v4/"+filename).done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){
        if (callback != undefined){
            if (scope != undefined) { callback.call(scope, true); }
            else { callback(true); }
        }
    });
}
```

А вызывающая функция может выглядеть вот так:

```
//...
var f = function (isLoaded) {
    if (isLoaded === true) {
        // ваши дальнейшие действия после загрузки скрипта
    }
};

loadjs("http://mysite/myfile.js", f, this);
//...
```

По завершению загрузки, будет вызвана функция f в среде где она находится (ссылка this, см. инфо про "call").